# DDR4 memory for HP ZBook Studio

Tags: laptop, memory, performance

I am currently looking at buying a [**HP Zbook Studio**](http://store.hp.com/us/en/ConfigureView?catalogId=10051&urlLangId=&langId=-1&storeId=10151&catEntryId=1150160&quantity=1) with an **Intel Core i7-6820HQ**, and I am looking at buying RAM separately. The best option on the HP website is **32 GB 2133 DDR4 SDRAM (2 DIMM)** (probably **CL15**). Let's assume that price is irrelevant.

I was looking at this option: **[Vengeance Series 32GB (2x16GB) DDR4 SODIMM 2666MHz CL18](http://www.corsair.com/en/vengeance-series-32gb-2x16gb-ddr4-sodimm-2666mhz-cl18-memory-kit-cmsx32gx4m2a2666c18)** .

My questions are:

- Is this memory compatible with the ZBook?
- Will this memory run at 2666MHz or will the computer/cpu limits its use at 2133Mhz?
- What will bring me more performances: the 2666Mhz CL18 or the 2133Mhz CL15?
- How big the performance difference will be?
- What will be the impact of 2666Mhz CL18 compared to the 2133Mhz CL15 in terms of energy consumption?

Comment: [Corsair Memory Finder](http://www.corsair.com/en-us/memory-finder)

Answer (score 1):

> Is this memory compatible with the ZBook?

Yes.

"Up to two SODIMMs, for system memory up to 32GB." - **[HP's website](http://m.hp.com/h20195/v2/GetPDF.aspx/c04832209.pdf)**

> Will this memory run at 2666MHz or will the computer/cpu limits its use at 2133Mhz?

I have never heard of RAM speeds being bound by a CPU, and even if it was IMO the performance increase is negligible in everyday tasks.

> What will bring me more performances: the 2666Mhz CL18 or the 2133Mhz CL15?

I'm almost positive that the former will be more expensive for starters. Now let's do some math.

**Ram Frequency** is expressed in Hertz, which means "cycles per second". So the 2666 ram will perform 2666 cycles per second, while the 2133 will perform 2133 cycles per second.

**Cas latency** is given in cycles, thus CAS 18 means it takes 18 cycles to respond, while CAS 15 means it will take 15 cycles to respond.

Now to do some math.

- **2666 RAM** will take 18/2666 seconds to respond or about 0.00675 seconds.
- **2133 RAM** will take 15/2133 seconds to respond, or about 0.00703 seconds.

So in conclusion, the 2666 is faster.

> How big the performance difference will be?

Around 0.00028 seconds.

> What will be the impact of 2666Mhz CL18 compared to the 2133Mhz CL15 in terms of energy consumption?

Honestly, I don't think it matters. The ram plays such a small part in the energy consumption in the machine it's probably negligible.